# What extension should I use to get the Value of the date from database using procedure and linq C#

Tags: c#, sql, linq

```cs
int diff = ((TimeSpan)(dateTimePicker1.Value.Date -aa.getCheckinDate(int.Parse(textBox2.Text)).ToList();)).Days;
```

I want to get the days between the date from a database and a date just set. I have use Procedure to get the date.

```sql
create procedure getCheckinDate
@num int
as
Select checkin_date from guesttransac WHERE g_number=@num
```

I use Linq to access the procedure

```cs
DataClasses1DataContext aa = new DataClasses1DataContext();
```

What should I use? `ToList()` is not working

```cs
aa.getCheckinDate(int.Parse(textBox2.Text)).ToList();
```

Comment: No, sorry I thought it will bold if I like that,

Comment: FYI: There's a preview of your question directly under the input box. You can see exactly what your question looks like before posting it.

Comment: I can't find the same question from mine. Thats why I posted.

Comment: Who is your comment for?

Comment: For you sir, How do I reply to your comment sir?

Comment: My comment was in reply to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65785664/what-extension-should-i-use-to-get-the-value-of-the-date-from-database-using-pro?noredirect=1#comment116313078_65785664) from you. It really doesn't relate to why you posted.

Comment: @DonMinSoo How many rows does your procedure return?